# Please explain this unexpected output of this JAVA program

Tags: java

In the following program I was jus t trying to create a simple class for as Circle `circ` and then tried to inherit a Cylinder from it `cylind`. I defined several methods to find the perimeter, area and volume of these geometrical objects but I am constantly getting wrong answer. I had spent several painstaking our hour to find the error but I am unable to find it. I am a beginner so I think there might be something I may have missed. Please help.

```
package com.company;
class circ {
    int radius;
    public circ(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
class cylind extends circ{
    int height;
    double area = (2*Math.PI * radius * ( radius + height ));
    double volume = (Math.PI * radius *radius * height );
    public cylind(int radius, int height) {
        super(radius);
        this.height = height;
    }
    public void area() {
        System.out.println("Total Surface Area = " + this.area);
    }
    public void volume(){
        System.out.println("Volume = " + this.volume);
    }
}
class Trial_and_error_2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        cylind b =new cylind(10,45);
        System.out.println(b.radius);
        System.out.println(b.height);
        System.out.println(2*Math.PI * b.radius * ( b.radius + b.height ));
        System.out.println(Math.PI * b.radius *b.radius * b.height );
        b.area();
        b.volume();
    }
}
```

Output: I have used `---->` to explain the output and the problem.

```
10   ---> Radius 
45   ---> height 
3455.7519189487725 ---> Surface area calculated in the main block
14137.16694115407  ---> Volume calculated in the main block
Total Surface Area = 628.3185307179587  ---> Wrong values of Surface area printed by the method of class THIS IS THE PROBLEM.
Volume = 0.0             ---> Wrong values of volume printed by the method of class THIS IS THE PROBLEM.
```

Comment: You initialize `double area` and `double volume` wrongfully; methods `area()` and `volume()` are rubbish.

Comment: Height is 0 the instant the area and volume are calculated. You should move the calculations to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your field calculations will be executed before the constructor.

Solution:
Just move calculations to constructor:

```
public Cylinder(int radius, int height) {
    super(radius);
    this.height = height;
    area = 2*Math.PI * radius * (radius + height);
    volume = Math.PI * radius *radius * height;
}
```

Also, I will recommend using full class names with a first capital.

Comment: This is not true. The super constructor is called *before* any field of th child class is initialized. [Here is an example](https://ideone.com/RZwet4). The actual problem here is that the `height` field is not yet set.

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables "area" and "volume" are initialized BEFORE the constructor is called. That's why you get volume = 0, because height is 0 when that happens.